Why does `#check add_mul (R := ℕ)` return `add_mul : ∀ (a b c : ℕ), (a + b) * c = a * c + b *` instead of `add_mul : Prop`?
I don't understand why #check add_mul (R := ℕ) returns add_mul : ∀ (a b c : ℕ), (a + b) * c = a * c + b * c instead of add_mul : prop. In my opinion add_mul (R := ℕ) is a proposition therefore Lean infoview should say add_mul : Prop (clearly I am wrong, and I want to know why).

Perhaps it's our naming convention that confuses you: since we don't care which element of these types we have, we just name an element after the type, instead of giving names according to the structure of the element.

You have two judgements here: the first one is that add_mul : ∀ (a b c : ℕ), (a + b) * c = a * c + b * c and the second one is that ∀ (a b c : ℕ), (a + b) * c = a * c + b * c : Prop

add_mul is a proof of ∀ (a b c : ℕ), (a + b) * c = a * c + b * c, not the proposition itself.
Consider the difference between these two:
def cat : ∀ (a b c : ℕ), (a + b) * c = a * c + b * c := by ...

def dog : Prop := ∀ (a b c : ℕ), (a + b) * c = a * c + b * c

The type of cat is ∀ (a b c : ℕ), (a + b) * c = a * c + b * c.
The type of dog is Prop.
